# remember last clicked dojo tab after page refresh/moving away and coming back to page

Tags: javascript, tabs, dojo

I have two dojo containers on page. The main container has three content panes (tabs), pane1, pane2 and pane3. Pane2 has another container which has two panes(tabs) again, pane2a and pane2b. What is the javascript code I write to make the last selected tabs remembered after refreshing/moving away and coming back to the same page. persist=true isn't working with my version of dojo. Please help.

Comment: it is persist=true.  perhaps you're using it incorrectly?  Which version of Dojo are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could use dojo.cookie() to set a cookie whenever a tab is selected, then read the cookie on page load and select the relevant tab.

Comment: As peller commented, this is already done automatically when `persist` is set to `true` on any StackContainer (which TabContainer descends from) - no need to do any cookie work manually. I'm seeing it as far back as 1.3 at least.

Comment: @ken : I have tabcontainers on the page and the tabs as content panes. persist does not work for me. i'm on dojo 1.2.2

Comment: could you please provide a code snippet? I'm really a n00b at this.